# Numerical Accuracy with scipy.optimize.curve_fit in Python

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-analysis

I am having issues with the numerical accuracy of scipy.optimize.curve_fit function in python. It seems to me that I can only get ~ 8 digits of accuracy when I desire ~ 15 digits. I have some data (at this point artificially created) made from the following data creation:

[image]

where term 1 ~ 10^-3, term 2 ~ 10^-6, and term 3 is ~ 10^-11. In the data, I vary `A` randomly (it is a Gaussian error). I then try to fit this to a model:

[image]

where lambda is a constant, and I only fit `alpha` (it is a parameter in the function). Now what I would expect is to see a linear relationship between `alpha` and `A` because terms 1 and 2 in the data creation are also in the model, so they should cancel perfectly;

[image]

So;

[image]

However, what happens is for small `A` (~10^-11 and below), `alpha` does not scale with `A`, that is to say, as `A` gets smaller and smaller, `alpha` levels out and remains constant.

For reference, I call the following: 
op, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(model, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=sig)

My first thought was that I was not using double precision, but I am pretty sure that python automatically creates numbers in double precision. Then I thought it was an issue with the documentation perhaps that cuts off the digits? Anyways, I could put my code in here but it is sort of complicated. Is there a way to ensure that the curve fitting function saves my digits?

Thank you so much for your help!

EDIT: The below is my code:

```
# Import proper packages
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
import scipy as sp
import scipy.constants as spc
import scipy.optimize as spo
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import ndarray as nda
from decimal import *

# Declare global variables
AU = 149597871000.0
test_lambda = 20*AU
M_Sun = (1.98855*(sp.power(10.0,30.0)))
M_Jupiter = (M_Sun/1047.3486)
test_jupiter_mass = M_Jupiter
test_sun_mass = M_Sun
rad_jup = 5.2*AU
ran = np.linspace(AU, 100*AU, num=100)
delta_a = np.power(10.0, -11.0)
chi_limit = 118.498

# Model acceleration of the spacecraft from the sun (with Yukawa term)
def model1(distance, A):
    return (spc.G)*(M_Sun/(distance**2.0))*(1 +A*(np.exp(-distance/test_lambda))) + (spc.G)*(M_Jupiter*distance)/((distance**2.0 + rad_jup**2.0)**(3.0/2.0)) 

# Function that creates a data point for test 1
def data1(distance, dela):
    return (spc.G)*(M_Sun/(distance**2.0) + (M_Jupiter*distance)/((distance**2.0 + rad_jup**2.0)**(3.0/2.0))) + dela

# Generates a list of 100 data sets varying by ~&a for test 1
def generate_data1():
    data_list = []
    for i in range(100):
        acc_lst = []
        for dist in ran:
            x = data1(dist, npr.normal(0, delta_a))
            acc_lst.append(x)
        data_list.append(acc_lst)
    return data_list

# Generates a list of standard deviations at each distance from the sun. Since &a is constant, the standard deviation of each point is constant
def generate_sig():
    sig = []
    for i in range(100):
        sig.append(delta_a)
    return sig

# Finds alpha for test 1, since we vary &a in test 1, we need to generate new data for each time we find alpha
def find_alpha1(data_list, sig):
    alphas = []
    for data in data_list:
        op, pcov = spo.curve_fit(model1, ran, data, p0=None, sigma=sig)
        alphas.append(op[0])
    return alphas

# Tests the dependence of alpha on &a and plots the dependence
def test1():
    global delta_a
    global test_lambda
    test_lambda = 20*AU
    delta_a = 10.0**-20.0
    alphas = []
    delta_as = []
    for i in range(20):
        print i
        data_list = generate_data1()
        print np.array(data_list[0])
        sig = generate_sig()
        alpha = find_alpha1(data_list, sig)    
        delas = []
        for alp in alpha:
            if alp < 0:
                x = 0
                plt.loglog(delta_a, abs(alp), '.' 'r')
            else: 
                x = 0
                plt.loglog(delta_a, alp, '.' 'b')
        delta_a *= 10
    plt.xlabel('Delta A')
    plt.ylabel('Alpha (at Lambda = 5 AU)')
    plt.show()

def main():
    test1()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: So you're saying that you think you're just fitting against mathematical noise?

Comment: I would like to see your code. What are the mean and variance of your "gaussian error"? What does "small `A`" mean? Small mean? Small variance? Small both? It seems to me that if `mean/variance >> 1` then you should expect `alpha` to follow the mean of `A`, but if `mean/variance << 1` then randomness will take over, and `alpha` will be zero-ish...

Comment: The code is too long to post here, should I post it in several comments?

Comment: Just because you DESIRE 15 digits does not mean you will get it. I DESIRE to win the lottery. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is to do with the minimisation algorithm used here, and the maximum obtainable precision.

I remember reading about it in numerical recipes a few years ago, I'll see if i can dig up a reference for you.

edit:

link to numerical recipes [here](http://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf) - skip down to page 394 and then read that chapter. Note the third paragraph on page 404:

> "Indulge us a ﬁnal reminder that `tol` should generally be no smaller
>   than the square root of your machine’s ﬂoating-point precision."

And [mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Built-inFunctions/AdvancedDocumentation/Optimization/UnconstrainedOptimization/1.3.html) mention that if you want accuracy, then you need to go for a different method, and that they don't infact use `LMA` unless the problem is recognised as being a sum of squares problem.

Given that you're just doing a one dimensional fit, it might be a good exercise to try just implementing one of the fitting algorithms they mention in that chapter.

What are you actually trying to achieve though? From what i understand about it, you're essentially trying to work out the amount of random noise you've added to the curve. But then that's not really what you're doing - unless i've understood wrong...

Edit2:

So after reading how you generate the data, there's an issue with the data and the model you're applying.

You're essentially fitting the two sides of this:

[image]

You're essentially trying to fit the *height* of a gaussian to random numbers. You're not fitting the gaussian to the frequency of those numbers.

Looking at your code, and judging from what you've said, this isn't you end goal, and you're just wanting to get used to the optimise method?

It would make more sense if you randomly adjusted the distance from the sun, and then fit to the data and see if you can minimise to find the distance which generated the data set?

Comment: Oh so you think it might be an issue with the algorithm itself? That's interesting, from the documentation it says that it uses the Levenberg Marquardt algorithm, I tried to look into it but it was a little over my head...

Comment: Just a quick read through of that shows it involves a least squares step. Because of the squaring, a `double` gives ~15 decimal digits of precision, so you half this - giving ~7-8. Is this what you're seeing?

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful, though is there any way to fix this if I still wanted to get to around 15 digits? Is there a python type that supports more digits? I know of the decimal module, but I don't think that many curve fitting algorithms accept decimal types as input

Comment: The "random noise" is generated in the generate_data() method, where I vary the data normally around the expected data with stdev of &a. Right here I am just trying to verify that I see a linear relationship between &a and alpha, eventually I want to fit to several parameters, but if I cannot get the numerical precision then I think I might need to use a different algorithm

Comment: I've used brent's method to fit a function with over a million parameters before, and it worked very nicely. I didn't need enormously high precision though, and Brent's method isn't going to get you closer than half the machine precision. I'd recommend getting close using the method you're using already, and then switch over to newton raphson once you're close using the parameters you get as a starting point.

Comment: I don't know how you're going to get 15 digits of precision for the parameters though.

Comment: Yeah, I think that I might switch to Mathematica because I think I can use arbitrary precision there (or so I've been told?). Thanks a bunch!!!